# Functional testing of a 3-rd party java program

Tags: java, testing, user-interface, functional-programming

I have a 3-rd party java application (I don't own source code) and I want to perform functional testing on it, similar to the way it's done in watin/watij/selenium/nunitforms etc. Can anyone suggest a library that I can use to do this sort of testing. What I'm interested in is clicking the applet's buttons, reading off text values, and the like. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already mentioned some testing frameworks. Why do they not work for you? If it's a Swing application you might want to have a look at [fest](http://code.google.com/p/fest/).